# For AutoComplete I am using json file as source. As it is downloading json file at client side. To reduce DB hit I am trying this. Is it best way?

Tags: javascript, json

For AutoComplete I am using json file as source. As it is downloading json file at client side. To reduce DB hit I am trying this. Is it best way?

Answer (score 0):

this is good way of saving resources. Storing fixed data in a json file gives you further possibilities to serve it from a CDN like cloudflare.

So yes, it is definitely a good way to go ;)

Comment: But problem is sometime json file size too large. eg : 3MB. In this case it is  taking too much time to download file at client side. Is there any solution for this??

Comment: hmm.. I would say this is another topic. accept this answer, create a new question and ping me, I'll check it out ;)